# Python OpenCV - Canny borders detection

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, canny-operator

I m trying to extract borders of a sample (see figure below). The gradient between it and the air seems important so I tried to used OpenCV Canny function, but the result is not satisfying (the second figure)... How I could improve the result?

You can find the picture here : https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=887799f6-f580-4579-8f75-148be4270cb0

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy import signal

median_optic_decentre = cv2.imread('median_plot.tiff',0)

edges = cv2.Canny(median_optic_decentre,10,60,apertureSize = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method of obtaining edges is using the Laplacian operator (described in the OpenCV docs [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html#laplacian-derivatives)). If you apply the Laplacian operator followed by some [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html), specifically [morphological opening](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening), the results look a bit better (if I'm understanding your question correctly):

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('median_plot.tiff')
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
S = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
morph_opened_laplacian = cv2.dilate(cv2.erode(laplacian, S), S)
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.gray()
plt.title("Original")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.title("Laplacian")
plt.imshow(laplacian)
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.title("Opened Laplacian")
plt.imshow(morph_opened_laplacian)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]